# How to make gcc warn about unknown functions?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Consider this code:

```
int function()
{
  int a = 1 ;
  int b = helper(&a);
  return b ;
}

int main()
{
  function();
  return 0 ;
}
```

This code snippet compiles to object code without problem using gcc, despite the fact that the function called 'helper' has not been declared. I know that the linker should catch this but I've seen obscure [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687508/why-does-c-tolerate-missing-function-declarations/11687573) which resolved once the correct headers (containing the function declarations) were included, despite the linker and compiler not generating any errors.

There are a number of gcc warnings which seem to be related but do not actually achieve what I want: -Wmissing-prototypes, -Wmissing-declarations and -Wstrict-prototypes. Unfortunately, these warnings are limited to missing prototypes when global functions are **defined**, I'm interested in warnings about missing prototypes when global functions are **referenced**.

Can anyone suggest alternatives?, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` warning.

Personally, I prefer compiling my code with `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: This is enabled by -Wall (which you should always use) and when using -std=c99.

Answer (score 4):

Use `-Wl,--no-undefined` to ensure a forced `undefined function` error.